# How to insert json array data into mysql database using spring mvc

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I read excel sheet and put all data into json array.Above json array look like this.

I want to save above json array data in my mysql database accoding to corresponding entities.

How to create it according to spring MVC + hibernate,..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Problem statement is fair enough ! Do you have any error in implementation ? If so share that...\

Comment: what have you tried ? any code snippet please. hint: create requstbody POJO class in POST request. Create ORM class for table, manage session and hibernate data manager then do some stuff, please go through tutorials. then data will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql 5.7 on wards we have JSON datatype. So you can create JSON type columns in database. for more info: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values

so define mapping as per that datatype in POJO or specify string type in POJO class.